# Second product attribute resets if first product attribute is changed

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a tshirt product on my Drupal Commerce webstore. The shirt has these options, in this order:

Size / 
Color / 
Sleeve Length

All shirts are available in all sizes/colors/sleeve lengths, so any combination of those three fields will yield a valid product.

If I choose a size, then a color, and then a sleeve length, there are no issues. However, if I choose a color first, and then choose a size, it resets my color to the original, default color. The same thing happens if I choose a sleeve length first and then change one of the other options.

Is there any way to fix this behavior so that the customer doesn't lose their selections? I'm afraid that they might not realize that their previously-selected options have been reverted to the defaults and I might end up with orders for the wrong size, color, or sleeve length.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in a pending feature request that probably just needs a little more patch review before being committed to Drupal Commerce: https://www.drupal.org/node/1286244